# Expose JSON as queryable for jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to expose some data, user names, as json format on my server. I want to use `jQuery.getJSOn()` method to query data. I can get my data converted to json with newtonsoft.dll on server and save it in a file. But as far as I know it is not queryable. I want something like

http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=?&q=abc

Can anyone help me out to expose my data ion the above format.

Comment: This seems more like a server-side scripting - what's your server setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to serve static JSON files your .dll produces, just put them in a folder on your web server.

Or code a web service that spits out JSON

if you put the files in a folder called json on example.com, and you calling getJSON from the same server, you should be good.

If you are asking how to generate web services, you need better tagging on this site.

**::ADDITIONAL RESPONSE::**

```
jQuery.getJSON('datanew.json',function (data) {
    var obj,i,dataLen,maxLen;
    maxLen = 5;
    i = 0;
    dataLen = data.length;
    do {
        if ( data[i].Name !== undefined ) {
            alert ( data[i].Name ); 
        }
        i = i + 1;
    } while ( i < dataLen && i < maxLen );
});
```

Comment: My json file on server is of the format:

"[{\"ContactID\":1,\"Name\":\"Gustavo Achong\"},{\"ContactID\":2,\"Name\":\"Catherine Abel\"}.......]

I am able to get all data from json file. I want specific data. Say I want only users whose names start with "A". My json file has all names. My code is like

$.getJSON("datanew.json", 
    function(data) {
        var newData = eval(data);
        $.each(newData, function(i, item) {
            alert(item.Name);
            if (i == 5) return false;
        });
    }
);